# does liferay use SQL*Net client by any means?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, liferay

Now I have some weird problem:

- our DBA blocked my OS user from connecting to the DEV database for some reason
- So I was not able to connect with TOAD
- but I was able to connect with SQL Developer
- also I wasn't able to start my Liferay server while connecting to the DEV database, with a message: user not allowed to login to the database (or something like this)

I made some investigation to tell why is SQL Developer connecting while TOAD is not. So I came out with a fact that TOAD uses the installed SQL*Net client while SQL Developer uses a standalone thin jdbc client.

So I thought this might be the reason somehow (not sure why, but may be the installed SQL*Net client reveals the OS user while thin client doesn't)

Now my question is: why is Liferay behaving the same way as TOAD though -according to my knowledge- it shouldn't as it is connected using datasource configured in the tomcat context.xml file?

Also if someone has a good scientific explanation about TOAD vs SQL developer, it's appreciated (I think I can track the sent request using wire shark, but no time actually)

I am using Liferay 6.1 , Liferay Studio and oracle 11g database

update :
I checked the connection of Liferay tomcat and found it :

`type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
 url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@.....`

Comment: What exactly did the DBA do?  My guess is that they created a login trigger that looks at some aspect of the session to allow or deny the login.  It would be common (but terribly insecure) to base some of that logic on the client program name so my first guess would be that TOAD was specifically blocked.  Without knowing what the DBA did specifically, it's hard to guess why one thing is working and another thing is not.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you can connect with SQLDeveloper and not with Liferay may be that your SQLDeveloper uses a more recent version of the JDBC thin driver (ojdbc6.jar or ojdbc7.jar). A solution would be to replace the one if Liferay with the one from SQLDeveloper. It would be just a matter of replacing the jar and restarting the tomcat server.